# How to fix the custom wordpress tag pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i had a problem with Category pagination and used that code to fix it but now i'm facing the same problem with tags,
The problem is tag pagination gives me error 404
here's the code

```
<?php
function remove_page_from_query_string($query_string)
{ 
    if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
        unset($query_string['name']);
        // 'page' in the query_string looks like '/2', so i'm spliting it out
        list($delim, $page_index) = split('/', $query_string['page']);
        $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
    }      
    return $query_string;
}
// I will kill you if you remove this. I died two days for this line 
add_filter('request', 'remove_page_from_query_string');

// following are code adapted from Custom Post Type Category Pagination Fix
function fix_category_pagination($qs){
          if( (isset($qs['category_name']) || isset($qs['author_name']) || isset($qs['tag']) ) && isset($qs['paged'])){
        $qs['post_type'] = get_post_types($args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            '_builtin' => false
        ));
        array_push($qs['post_type'],'post');
    }
    return $qs;
}
add_filter('request', 'fix_category_pagination');
?>
```

Comment: Do you expect us to read your thoughts and see the problem?

Comment: The problem is tag pagination gives me error 404